# How to build a route that correspond to Angular routes from server side?

Tags: angular, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a website build with Angular 7 and ASP.net Core 2.2. I make the standard "EmailConfirmed", "ResetPasswordRequest" and "ResetPasswordConfirmed" features.
All of those have their routes defined in app.route.ts like below:

```
{ path: 'email-confirmed', component: AccountEmailConfirmedComponent },
{ path: 'reset-password-request', component: AccountResetPasswordRequestComponent },
{ path: 'reset-password-confirmed', component: AccountResetPasswordConfirmedComponent }
```

In server side now, I must send an email with the appropriate template and links.

The code I have made work well, but the callback URL have to correspond with angular route which isn't the case here.

I would want to know the best manner to build the callback url for this case

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPasswordRequest(string email)
    {
         var user = await _userService._manager.FindByNameAsync(email);
         if (user != null && await _userService._manager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {
               string token = await _userService._manager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
               // build from angular route dynamically....
               string angularCallbackUrl = "https://localhost:44350/reset-password-confirmed";

string callbackUrl = this._urlHelper.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new ConfirmTokenModel(user.Id, token), protocol: this.HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

                        await this._emailService.SendAsync(
                            to: user.Email,
                            subject: "Reset password",
                            body: "Reset your password by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");

                        return new OkObjectResult("success");
                    }

                    return new ObjectResult("failed") { StatusCode = 403 };
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either building a http service that your 3 route components can access, or use 1 component that is shared with all 3 routes. You will use an http function call to send a request to your backend server. That http function call will then expect a response back, which I'm assuming you then want to use that response for the specified route. Those route components will need access to the response back from the server, so either you put the http function call in a service which all 3 route components can access, or you have that http function call in 1 component that is used by all 3 routes.